# what is for....in statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

anyone can explain how to use for...in statement in javascript. I had read the w3school article but i think it is not so clear.Below is the code, please explain this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x;
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[10] = "Saab";
mycars[20] = "Volvo";
mycars[30] = "BMW";

for (x in mycars)
{
document.write(mycars[x] + "<br />");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`for in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will iterate through every property in an object.

In your example, the `x` variable will cycle through every property in the `mycars` object.

If you add `mycars.expensive = "Porsche";`, it will find that too.

---

Note that, as stated by [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), `for in` loops should *not* be used to loop through ordinary arrays:

> Although it may be tempting to use
>   this as a way to iterate over an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array),
>   this is a bad idea. The
>   `for...in` statement
>   iterates over user-defined properties
>   in addition to the array elements, so
>   if you modify the array's non-integer
>   or non-positive properties (e.g. by
>   adding a `"foo"` property
>   to it or even by adding a method or
>   property to
>   `Array.prototype`), the
>   `for...in` statement will
>   return the name of your user-defined
>   properties in addition to the numeric
>   indexes. Also, because order of
>   iteration is arbitrary, iterating over
>   an array may not visit elements in
>   numeric order. Thus it is better to
>   use a traditional [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for) loop with a numeric index when
>   iterating over arrays. Similar
>   arguments might be used against even
>   using for...in at all (at least
>   without [propertyIsEnumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)()
>   or hasOwnProperty()
>   checks), since it will also iterate
>   over Object.prototype (which, though
>   usually discouraged, can, as in the
>   case of Array.prototype, be usefully
>   extended by the user where are no
>   namespacing concerns caused by
>   inclusion of other libraries which
>   might not perform the above checks on
>   such iterations and where they are
>   aware of the effect such extension
>   will have on their own use of
>   iterators such as for...in).

Comment: it only can apply to an array?

Comment: `for in` loops can be used with any object, but should not be used for ordinary arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First you create an **object** with 3 items (and not an Array)

```
  var mycars = new Object();
  mycars[10] = "Saab";
  mycars[20] = "Volvo";
  mycars[30] = "BMW";
```

where `10`, `20` and `30` are the object properties.
then you want to navigate through the object, visit all properties and display each value associated to a property.

This is where the [ `for` (*variable* `in` *object*) *expression* ] javascript construction intervenes: 
The *variable* will be set to the first property of the object, then to the 2nd, then to the last. Try

```
  for (v in mycars) alert(v);
```

to see how it works, and this as well

```
  for (v in mycars) alert("Property: "+v+", value: "+mycars[v]);
```

Comment: You should not advocate using `for..in` with `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for ... in` construction iterates over every element within the object on the right side of `in`. In your case, the block below the `for` statement is executed once for every car in `mycars`.

Answer (score 0):

`for in` is a way of burying bugs for later generations to discover.  As has been copiously pointed out, if applied to an Array, it will loop through all the elements of the array, and the length of the array, and whatever other data happens to be attached to the array.  Applying it to an ordinary object is better, but you still should still filter the indices through `hasOwnProperty`.

Better to use a framework-provided function like jQuery's `$.each`