# How did this program get me the values of property of the object?

Tags: javascript, this, for-in-loop

```
var nyc = {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Michael Bloomberg",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
};

var myProperty = this.nyc;
/*this is one variable so how can it store all the values and what does this.nyc mean
and what value it carries, value of all property or just the value of one property*/
for(myProperty in nyc){console.log(nyc[myProperty]);}
//how is this line giving me the value of all the properties of object.
```

How does basically for in loop works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is for....in statement in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559491/what-is-for-in-statement-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

`myProperty` is set to a new value at each iteration of the `for` loop. So the old value of `myProperty` does not matter.

Comment: In fact, the assignment on top of the loop is redundant and highly confusing. A plain `var myProperty;` would have been better.

Comment: @Thilo: I agree. I think this is a symptom of his core confusion--he does not understand why, after assigning a particular property to `myProperty` it can still be used to enumerate all of them.